# What are the possible reactions of clicking an ad inside an app?

Tags: applications, malware

From famous and "trusted" android apps to not so famous and "risky" apps:

1. What actions can be triggered by clicking on an advertisement inside
   the application ?
2. Could just that click install a virus to your smartphone or tamper
   with your smartphones settings, or maybe the standardization of the
   ads by Google Play prevent this from happening ?
3. I have found a way to prevent URL redirection and that's by not
   setting the default Browser app. Therefore, when clicking to an ad,
   I get prompt to choose my preferred browser. If I press the back
   button, nothing executes or am I wrong ?
4. Are there other actions apart from URL redirections or redirections
   to the Google Play store ?
5. Does different Android Version behave differently as to clicking an
   ad ? if so what's the reaction for every different Android Version ?

P.S:

- I am not looking a way to block the advertisements. I want to know the possible actions that can be triggered by clicking an ad.
- We also assume that the smartphone is NOT rooted.

Comment: About **1.**, your balance can be deducted. That's certain (I'm a victim :D ). About **2.**, a drive-by download is possible though I don't know how it will be installed without user interaction.

Comment: In addition to answer(s) that you may receive here, perhaps, it would be good if you experience the possibilities on your own. Fire up Android x86 `.iso` in Virtualbox/vmware and emulate the real world scenario there, or take a complete backup of your phone and then do the testing on the phone itself. Just saying. I would definitely go to such length if I had such burning question. :)

Comment: while clicking an ad may install a new hidden app . Hidden app is one that does not create launcher icon of itself and can be harmful to your mobile.

Comment: @Firelord I have emulated the process of clicking an ad both in an Android PC emulator and in my smartphone. Using the emulator, clicking an ad always triggered a URL. Using my smartphone, clicking on ads triggered URL redirections and Google Play Links to apps that have to do with phone boosting. The thing I do not know is if this click triggers a process in the background which I cannot see.
P.S: The app I used to click ads was Ookla SpeedTest.

Comment: @pgmank Monitor this click process by the events in `adb logcat`. You'll come to know  if something else is getting executed when you click those ads.